# Does globas sections form an exact sequence?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $(X,\mathscr A)$ a ringed space and $0\to\mathscr F\overset{u_X}\to\mathscr G\overset{v_X}\to\mathscr H$ an exact sequence of $\mathscr A$-module homomorphisms. Is the sequence 
$$0\to\Gamma(X,\mathscr F)\overset{u_X}\to \Gamma(X,\mathscr G)\overset{v_X}\to\Gamma(X,\mathscr H)$$
always exact?

Comment: Yes, since $\Gamma(X,-)\cong\text{Hom}_{\mathscr A}({\mathscr A},-)$ this is a special case of the left exactness of $\text{Hom}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Hint:* Given $0\to\mathscr F\overset{u_X}\to\mathscr G\overset{v_X}\to\mathscr H$ exact. It can be shown that for every open $U \subseteq X,0\to\Gamma(U,\mathscr F)\overset{u_X}\to \Gamma(U,\mathscr G)\overset{v_X}\to\Gamma(U,\mathscr H)$ is exact.

(1). Show that $u_X$ is exact if and only if $u_X(U)$ is exact for every open $U \subseteq X.$

(2). Use $u_X$ injective to show that the image presheaf $V \mapsto v_X(V)$ is actually a sheaf.